# How to set a String Variable to be used in a MySQL query in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to set a text/string variable to be used throughout some MySQL queries in phpMyAdmin. I can create a numeric variable but I am wondering if I can do the same with the text string.

Here is a selection of some of my MySQL query statements:

```
    -- copies abc_wordpress.wp_usermeta to xyz_wordpress.wp_usermeta;
    USE abc_wordpress;
    OPTIMIZE TABLE wp_usermeta;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wp_usermeta_source;
    CREATE TABLE wp_usermeta_source LIKE wp_usermeta;
    INSERT INTO wp_usermeta_source SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta;
    -- the following numeric variable works perfectly
    SET @count = 466;
    UPDATE wp_usermeta_source SET umeta_id = @count:= @count + 1;
    -- END working numeric variable
    ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta_source AUTO_INCREMENT=467;
    UPDATE wp_usermeta_source SET meta_key = "wp_22_capabilities" WHERE meta_key = "wp_capabilities";
    UPDATE wp_usermeta_source SET meta_key = "wp_22_user_level" WHERE meta_key = "wp_user_level";
    UPDATE wp_usermeta_source SET meta_key = "wp_22_user-settings" WHERE meta_key = "wp_user-settings";
    UPDATE wp_usermeta_source SET meta_key = "wp_22_user-settings-time" WHERE meta_key = "wp_user-settings-time";
    INSERT INTO wp_usermeta_source ( user_id, meta_key, meta_value ) SELECT ID, "source_domain", "dev.example.com" FROM wp_users;
...
```

What I want to do is create 2 variables. One that stores `_source` and the other that stores `_22_`. Is it possible? I tried `SET @source = "_source"` and `SET @site = "_22_"` but I could not get them to work after many attempts and variations.

Is it possible to do?

**Amended for Better Clarity**

How can I do this, if at all?

```
@sourceVar = "_source";
@tableID = "22";
...
UPDATE wp_usermeta_@sourceVar SET meta_key = "wp_@tableID_user_level" WHERE meta_key = "wp_user_level";
...
```